# Creating a variable with sed in ksh

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh

I'm using Ksh88 on a Solaris 10 machine.

If I do the following:

```
foo="one two three"
for i in $foo; do
    echo $i;
done
```

The script executes as expected:

```
$ ./script.ksh
one
two
three
```

However if I replace the loop with this:

```
foo="one two three"
for i in $(sed -e 's/bar/$foo/' <(echo $1));
do
    echo $i
done
```

I execute it and this is what I get:

```
$ ./script.ksh bar
$foo
```

How can I make `for` expand the result of the `sed` command into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -e 's/bar/$foo/' <(echo $1)` prints `$foo`. The result of a command expansion is not subject to shell syntax processing. It is only subject to field splitting (splitting into words) filename generation (i.e. globbing), when you use it this way outside double quotes.

In any shell, if you have the name of a variable in another variable, you can obtain the value of that variable with `eval`.

```
variable_name=$(sed -e 's/bar/foo/' <(echo $1))
case $variable_name in
  *[!0-9A-Z_a-z]*) echo 1>&2 "Invalid variable name: $variable_name"; exit 3;;
esac
eval variable_value="\${$variable_name}"
for i in $variable_value; do …
```

Note that `$variable_value` not only breaks up the value into whitespace-delimited parts, but also performs globbing (i.e. expands wildcards into file names) on the parts. To turn off globbing, call `set +f` beforehand.

In ksh93, there is a special flag you can use when defining a variable `var`, which tells the shell that the value of the variable is itself a variable name and that `$var` must expand to the value of the variable whose name is `$var`. Also, you should make `foo` an array, since it's really a list of strings and not a string.

```
foo=(one two three)
typeset -n variable_name="$(sed -e 's/bar/foo/' <(echo $1))"
for i in "${variable_name[@]}"; do …
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/[\\\/]/\\&/g') # only required if $foo can contain one of \/
set +f     # only required if $foo contains one of \[*?
for i in $(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/bar/$foo/"); do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Yuck. What if `$foo` contains a `/`?

Comment: There is no indication it can contain / in the OP question but I'm taking your point into account anyway.